# How can we improve the 'filter' tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have [13 questions on the site tagged with 'filter'](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filter). If you didn't already realise that "filter" can mean more than one thing, that list would educate you: it has questions about filtered internet connections (that block certain websites or protocols), on-device web filters for children, sound recordings that filter some frequencies, mail filtering, and hiding posts in Facebook.

These questions are pretty unrelated, and having one tag with so many meanings is worthless. What can we do to improve the situation? Should we just remove this one tag, or can we replace it with more useful ones?

Answer (score 2):

- "Replacing with more useful ones" IMHO makes not much sense, with 13 questions altogether. That would mean at least 5 tags with probably less than 3-4 questions each.
- Seeing the tags in combinations, they seem to make sense. Browsing e.g. the `gmail` tag and see a question additionally tagged `filter`, the meaning is pretty clear. Also initiating a search for `[gmail] [filter]` would yield the corresponding result(s).
- Most questions could probably be re-tagged (or have the `filter` tag simply removed).

All depends on how you look at tags, and I'm a bit torn between two thoughts: If you think about tags as "filters" (sic!), I'd say we leave is as-is. If, however, each tag should have a significant and specific meaning, there's no way for a `filter` tag to survive: As shown by the existing usage (and I wonder there's not also a question on screen-/display-filters), it would be much too broad – and stand-alone tags for each of the different meanings would turn out in tags with 1-4 questions each, which wouldn't be very useful either.

---

I'd rather say declaring `filter` a "generic tag", as it is currently used, and give it a corresponding description, e.g.:

> for questions involving a filtering process of any kind. This is to be used in conjunction with a descriptive tag giving it a real meaning, don't use it stand-alone.

It's tag-wiki could give some more elaborate examples then of how to use it and how not to use it.

Comment: I agree. Some tags are meant to be used with other tags / filters. This just boils down to knowing how to use the search function to your advantage.